# Deleting a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a dataframe like below after transposing and adding few columns.

Initial df-

```
                         plan_benefits  value                    plan_benefits_db value_db  valid_flag
0            durable_medical_equipment     20           durable_medical_equipment       40       False
1                                  pcp     45                                 pcp       40       False
2                           specialist     80                          specialist       40       False
3                           diagnostic   7540                          diagnostic       40       False
4                              imaging    300                             imaging       40       False
5                              generic     30                             generic    40500       False
6                      formulary_brand    110                     formulary_brand    40500       False
7                non_preferred_generic  55110               non_preferred_generic    40500       False
8                       emergency_room    350                      emergency_room       40       False
9                   inpatient_facility     20                  inpatient_facility       40       False
10           medical_deductible_single   2000           medical_deductible_single     6000       False
11           medical_deductible_family   4000           medical_deductible_family    12000       False
12  maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_single   7550  maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_single     6650       False
13  maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_family  15100  maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_family    13300       False
```

Final df -

```
  plan_benefits  durable_medical_equipment    pcp  specialist  diagnostic  imaging  generic  formulary_brand  non_preferred_generic  emergency_room  inpatient_facility  medical_deductible_single  medical_deductible_family  maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_single  maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_family plan_name      pdf_name
    valid_flag                         False  False       False       False    False    False            False                  False           False               False                      False                      False                               False                               False   ABCBCBC  adjnajdn.pdf
```

Operations I have performed-

```
    df_repo = df_repo[['plan_benefits', 'valid_flag']].set_index('plan_benefits').transpose()

    df_repo['plan_name'] = 'ABCBCBC'
    df_repo['pdf_name'] = 'adjnajdn.pdf'
    # df_repo = df_repo.drop('plan_benefits', 1)

    print(df_repo.to_string())
```

I need to remove the first column 'plan_benefits'. When using `drop()`, I am getting `KeyError: "['plan_benefits'] not found in axis"`

I have tried multiple options like del df['plan_benefits'] but nothing is working.

Final after the answers in the comments -

```
 durable_medical_equipment    pcp  specialist  diagnostic  imaging  generic  formulary_brand  non_preferred_generic  emergency_room  inpatient_facility  medical_deductible_single  medical_deductible_family  maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_single  maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_family plan_name      pdf_name
0                      False  False       False       False    False    False            False                  False           False               False                      False                      False                               False                               False   ABCBCBC  adjnajdn.pdf
```

Comment: @Jezrael when I print print(df_repo.index.name) I am already getting `None.`

Comment: And `print(df_repo.columns.name)` ?

Comment: I get `plan_benefits`

Comment: So use `df_repo.columns.name = None`

Comment: But the value of this column is still there `valid_flag`

Comment: So use also `df_repo = df_repo.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. The column has been deleted . But I am getting a 0 as an index when I print (see updated question). Can I remove that as well . Because when I am writing the dataframe to an excel I am getting that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is necessary remove columns name and create default index:

```
df = (df_repo[['plan_benefits', 'valid_flag']].set_index('plan_benefits')
              .T.reset_index(drop=True))
df.columns.name = None
```

Or:

```
df = (df_repo[['plan_benefits', 'valid_flag']]
        .set_index('plan_benefits')
        .transpose()
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print (df)
   durable_medical_equipment    pcp  specialist  diagnostic  imaging  generic  \
0                      False  False       False       False    False    False   

   formulary_brand  non_preferred_generic  emergency_room  inpatient_facility  \
0            False                  False           False               False   

   medical_deductible_single  medical_deductible_family  \
0                      False                      False   

   maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_single  maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_family  
0                               False                               False
```

And last add `index=False` to [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

---

Btw, because index is removed, solution should be simplify:

```
df = df_repo[['plan_benefits', 'valid_flag']].set_index('plan_benefits').transpose()
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```